# Trouble updating a "trivia game" code written in python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, reference, local-variables, python-3.3

I am trying to get the code for a trivia game written in python 2 to run in python 3. Here is what I've gotten so far, but I'm just too confused at this point. None of the multiple choice answers will display (just numbers).

```
# the start of a state trivia game

import random

# create placeholder lists for 50 items each
state = list(range(50))
capital = list(range(50))
date = list(range(50))
flower = list(range(50))
bird = list(range(50))

# populate the lists
state[0] = "Alabama"
capital[0] = "Montgomery"
date[0] = "December 14, 1819"
flower[0] = "Camellia"
bird[0] = "Yellowhammer"

state[1] = "Alaska"
capital[1] = "Juneau"
date[1] = "January 3, 1959"
flower[1] = "Forget-me-not"
bird[1] = "Willow Ptarmigan"

state[2] = "Arizona"
capital[2] = "Phoenix"
date[2] = "February 14, 1912"
flower[2] = "Suguaro Cactus Blossom"
bird[2] = "Cactus Wren"

state[3] = "Arkansas"
capital[3] = "Little Rock"
date[3] = "June 15, 1836"
flower[3] = "Apple Blossom"
bird[3] = "Mockingbird"

state[4] = "California"
capital[4] = "Sacremento"
date[4] = "September 9, 1850"
flower[4] = "Golden Poppy"
bird[4] = "California Valley Quail"

state[5] = "Colorado"
capital[5] = "Denver"
date[5] = "August 1, 1876"
flower[5] = "Mountain Columbine"
bird[5] = "Lark Bunting"

state[6] = "Connecticut"
capital[6] = "Hartford"
date[6] = "January 9, 1788"
flower[6] = "Mountain Laurel"
bird[6] = "Robin"

state[7] = "Florida"
capital[7] = "Tallahassee"
date[7] = "March 3, 1845"
flower[7] = "Orange Blossom"
bird[7] = "Mockingbird"

state[8] = "Georgia"
capital[8] = "Atlanta"
date[8] = "January 2, 1788"
flower[8] = "Cherokee Rose"
bird[8] = "Brown Thrasher"

state[9] = "Hawaii"
capital[9] = "Honolulu"
date[9] = "August 21, 1959"
flower[9] = "Red Hibiscus"
bird[9] = "Nene (Hawaiian Goose)"

state[10] = "Idaho"
capital[10] = "Boise"
date[10] = "July 3, 1890"
flower[10] = "Syringa"
bird[10] = "Mountain Bluebird"

state[11] = "Illinois"
capital[11] = "Springfield"
date[11] = "December 3, 1818"
flower[11] = "Violet"
bird[11] = "Cardinal"

state[12] = "Indiana"
capital[12] = "Indianapolis"
date[12] = "December 11, 1816"
flower[12] = "Peony"
bird[12] = "Cardinal"

state[13] = "Iowa"
capital[13] = "Des Moines"
date[13] = "December 28, 1846"
flower[13] = "Wild Rose"
bird[13] = "Eastern Goldfinch"

state[14] = "Kansas"
capital[14] = "Topeka"
date[14] = "January 29, 1861"
flower[14] = "Sunflower"
bird[14] = "Western Meadowlark"

state[15] = "Kentucky"
capital[15] = "Frankfort"
date[15] = "June 1, 1792"
flower[15] = "Goldenrod"
bird[15] = "Cardinal"

state[16] = "Louisiana"
capital[16] = "Baton Rouge"
date[16] = "April 30, 1812"
flower[16] = "Magnolia"
bird[16] = "Eastern Brown Pelican"

state[17] = "Maine"
capital[17] = "Augusta"
date[17] = "March 15, 1820"
flower[17] = "Pine Cone & Tassel"
bird[17] = "Chickadee"

state[18] = "Tennessee"
capital[18] = "Nashville"
date[18] = "June 1, 1796"
flower[18] = "Iris"
bird[18] = "Mockingbird"

state[19] = "Maryland"
capital[19] = "Annapolis"
date[19] = "April 28, 1788"
flower[19] = "Black-eyed Susan"
bird[19] = "Baltimore Oriole"

state[20] = "Delaware"
capital[20] = "Dover"
date[20] = "December 7, 1787"
flower[20] = "Peach Blossom"
bird[20] = "Blue Hen Chicken"

state[21] = "Massachusetts"
capital[21] = "Boston"
date[21] = "February 6, 1788"
flower[21] = "Mayflower"
bird[21] = "Chickadee"

state[22] = "Rhode Island"
capital[22] = "Providence"
date[22] = "May 29, 1790"
flower[22] = "Violet"
bird[22] = "Rhode Island Red"

state[23] = "Minnesota"
capital[23] = "St. Paul"
date[23] = "May 11, 1858"
flower[23] = "Lady-slipper"
bird[23] = "Loon"

state[24] = "Mississippi"
capital[24] = "Jackson"
date[24] = "December 10, 1817"
flower[24] = "Magnolia"
bird[24] = "Mockingbird"

state[25] = "Missouri"
capital[25] = "Jefferson City"
date[25] = "August 10, 1821"
flower[25] = "Hawthorn"
bird[25] = "Bluebird"

state[26] = "Michigan"
capital[26] = "Lansing"
date[26] = "January 26, 1837"
flower[26] = "Apple Blossom"
bird[26] = "Robin"

state[27] = "Montana"
capital[27] = "Helena"
date[27] = "November 8, 1889"
flower[27] = "Bitterroot"
bird[27] = "Western Meadowlark"

state[28] = "Nebraska"
capital[28] = "Lincoln"
date[28] = "March 1, 1867"
flower[28] = "Goldenrod"
bird[28] = "Western Meadowlark"

state[29] = "Nevada"
capital[29] = "Carson City"
date[29] = "October 31, 1864"
flower[29] = "Sagebrush"
bird[29] = "Mountain Bluebird"

state[30] = "New Hampshire"
capital[30] = "Concord"
date[30] = "June 21, 1788"
flower[30] = "Purple Lilac"
bird[30] = "Purple Finch"

state[31] = "Vermont"
capital[31] = "Montpelier"
date[31] = "March 4, 1791"
flower[31] = "Red Clover"
bird[31] = "Hermit Thrush"

state[32] = "New Jersey"
capital[32] = "Trenton"
date[32] = "December 18, 1787"
flower[32] = "Violet"
bird[32] = "Eastern Goldfinch"

state[33] = "New Mexico"
capital[33] = "Santa Fe"
date[33] = "January 6, 1912"
flower[33] = "Yucca"
bird[33] = "Road Runner"

state[34] = "New York"
capital[34] = "Albany"
date[34] = "July 26, 1788"
flower[34] = "Rose"
bird[34] = "Bluebird"

state[35] = "North Carolina"
capital[35] = "Raleigh"
date[35] = "November 21, 1789"
flower[35] = "Flowering Dogwood"
bird[35] = "Cardinal"

state[36] = "Wyoming"
capital[36] = "Cheyenne"
date[36] = "July 10, 1890"
flower[36] = "Indian Paintbrush"
bird[36] = "Meadowlark"

state[37] = "North Dakota"
capital[37] = "Bismarck"
date[37] = "November 2, 1889"
flower[37] = "Prairie Rose"
bird[37] = "Meadowlark"

state[38] = "Ohio"
capital[38] = "Columbus"
date[38] = "March 1, 1803"
flower[38] = "Scarlet Carnation"
bird[38] = "Cardinal"

state[39] = "Oklahoma"
capital[39] = "Oklahoma City"
date[39] = "November 16, 1907"
flower[39] = "Mistletoe"
bird[39] = "Scissor-tailed Flycatcher"

state[40] = "Oregon"
capital[40] = "Salem"
date[40] = "February 14, 1859"
flower[40] = "Oregon Grape"
bird[40] = "Western Meadowlark"

state[41] = "Pennsylvania"
capital[41] = "Harrisburg"
date[41] = "December 12, 1787"
flower[41] = "Mountain Laurel"
bird[41] = "Ruffed Grouse"

state[42] = "South Carolina"
capital[42] = "Columbia"
date[42] = "May 23, 1788"
flower[42] = "Yellow Jessamine"
bird[42] = "Carolina Wren"

state[43] = "South Dakota"
capital[43] = "Pierre"
date[43] = "November 2, 1889"
flower[43] = "Pasqueflower"
bird[43] = "Ring-necked Pheasant"

state[44] = "Texas"
capital[44] = "Austin"
date[44] = "December 29, 1845"
flower[44] = "Bluebonnet"
bird[44] = "Mockingbird"

state[45] = "Utah"
capital[45] = "Salt Lake City"
date[45] = "January 4, 1896"
flower[45] = "Sego Lily"
bird[45] = "Sea Gull"

state[46] = "Virginia"
capital[46] = "Richmond"
date[46] = "June 26, 1788"
flower[46] = "Dogwood"
bird[46] = "Cardinal"

state[47] = "Washington"
capital[47] = "Olympia"
date[47] = "November 11, 1889"
flower[47] = "Coast Rhododendron"
bird[47] = "Willow Goldfinch"

state[48] = "West Virginia"
capital[48] = "Charleston"
date[48] = "June 20, 1863"
flower[48] = "Rhododendron"
bird[48] = "Cardinal"

state[49] = "Wisconsin"
capital[49] = "Madison"
date[49] = "May 29, 1848"
flower[49] = "Wood Violet"
bird[49] = "Robin"


def state_flower():

    #ask a multiple choice question about the state flower with four possible answers
    # pick a list of 4 unique integers from a list of integers 0 to 49
    # the first integer will match the state in the question and the
    # correct flower, the other 3 will be false choices

    pick = random.sample(range(50), 4)

    print("The state flower of %s is:" % state[pick[0]])
    answer = list(range(4))
    for k in range(4):
        # a little trick, the correct answer ends with an invisible space
        # rstrip() makes sure the flower name itself does not end with a space
        if k == 0:
            answer[k] = "%s " % flower[pick[k]].rstrip()
        else:
            answer[k] = "%s" % flower[pick[k]].rstrip()

    # randomize the mutiple choice answers, chr(65+n) adds A), B) ...
    choice = []
    answer = range(4)
    n = 0
    for k in random.sample(range(4),4):
        choice.append("%s) %s" % (chr(65+n), answer[k]))
        print(choice[n])
        n += 1

    # get the answer and check it
    letter = input("Select A, B, C or D: ")
    correct_flag = False
    for answer in choice:
        # the one with the trailing space is correct
        if answer.endswith(" "):
            correct = answer
            # does it contain the selected letter? For instance D)
            if letter.upper()+')' in correct:
                correct_flag = True

    # show the result
    if correct_flag == True:
        print(correct ,"is correct!")
    else:
        print("The correct answer is", correct)

state_flower()
```

Here is what happens when I run it, and now I'm totally lost on how to fix it...

```
The state flower of Wisconsin is:
A) 0
B) 3
C) 2
D) 1
Select A, B, C or D: A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes...", line 357, in state_flower
    print("The correct answer is", correct)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'correct' referenced before assignment
```

Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

"correct" is a variable inside an if condition and is not set as a global variable inside the definition, so the line "print("The correct answer is", correct)" can't reach to the variable "correct". You can easily fix it by defining what correct is at the start of def state_flower():

Comment: So, when I define 'correct' it just prints what value I assigned it. I defined it like so: correct = None , but now it prints "The correct answer is None" after I choose any answer. Also, I still don't have "choices" for the multiple choice answers, just numbers for some reason I can't figure out. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: answer = range(4) --> You are making the answer variable this: answer = [0,1,2,3] and in choice, you put 0, 1, 2 and 3 as answers.

Comment: I'd use class instead of making what you are trying to do a function. That way, you can easily access to global variables by using the __init

Comment: So I'm a little confused (just a beginner). When I change the answer and choice like you said the program does nothing. It runs, but prints nothing. Also, I'm not clear on using class. I intent to add more functions to ask questions about other subjects like "What is [state]'s state bird?" Sorry this is quite a difficult project for my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out, answer = range(4) does not belong in this section of code.

```
# randomize the mutiple choice answers, chr(65+n) adds A), B) ...
    choice = []
 #-->answer = range(4)
    n = 0
    for k in random.sample(range(4),4):
        choice.append("%s) %s" % (chr(65+n), answer[k]))
        print(choice[n])
        n += 1
```

Thanks for the help!